# Could not determine java version from 10.0.1 react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i am beginner to react-native i just created my first react native app and tried to run in Android it gives me this error
I've successfully installed java and Android Studio in mac.[image]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: You can either upgrade your gradle, by opening the project in android studio and accepting to upgrade it (a prompt should appear) or you can downgrade your java version. Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17688)

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp thanks for the reply let me do this

Answer (score 0):

Installing Java8 Worked for me.

```
brew cask uninstall java
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

Answer (score 0):

open the project in Android Studio

build & run

after that

cd your_project/android
react-native start